# Wicket: avoid 302-redirect to homepage

Tags: java, wicket, servlet-filters

Our wicket-based website has mounted the home page as `/index.html`. Currently, when the user enters `www.ourdomain.com` in the browser, wicket automatically sends a 302-redirect to `www.ourdomain.com/index.html`. I want to avoid this redirect for some reasons.

I've tried a `ServletFilter` implementation

```
...
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);
...
```

but this caused only a 404 response. I've also tried modifying the `StringBuffer` returned by `request.getRequestURL()` followed by `chain.doFilter(request, response);` but also without success.

What else I could try to let wicket return the home page (without mounting at a different path) for the no-path-URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create decendant class of the class you mount to index.html and use it in Application#getHomePage

Here is an example:

```
   public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

        @Override
        protected void init() {
            super.init();
            ...
            mountPage("index.html", IndexPage.class);
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
           return HomePage.class;
        }

        public static class HomePage extends IndexPage{}

    }
```

Comment: Tried on a simple app, works without redirects. Note: I used different classes in #getHomepage and in the mount.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Now I see you are subclassing the mounted page.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not helped me using Wicket 7.4 and glassfish 3 and IE11

Answer (score 5):

Put that in your `init()` method of the application class

```
    @Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
    getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
}
```

take a look in my default init() method

```
    @Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
    getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency(isTest() ? ONE_SECOND : null);
    getResourceSettings().setDefaultCacheDuration(isTest() ? MAXIMUM : null);
    getMarkupSettings().setCompressWhitespace(true);
    getMarkupSettings().setStripComments(true);
    getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(true);
    getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
}
```

In wicket 6 use:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
```

Comment: unfortunately the ONE_PASS_RENDER solves one problem but generates another one like POST request will not be redirected as required normally so reloading the page cause exceptions (and many others problems)

Comment: still I have the same issue with IE11, glassfish 3 and Wicket 7.3, 7.4 as well. I was able to do some hack in 7.2 but I do not like I would like perfect solution. so I am still looking for solution (Chrome, Firefox works, the problem only belongs to IE)